# Probability inequality with abs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\xi1, \xi2, \xi3$ - independent and have symmetrical probability distribution where center of symmetry is 0. Let $P(|\xi1+\xi2+\xi3| \leqslant C)=1$, where $C > 0$. Prove that $P(|\xi1|+|\xi2|+|\xi3| \leqslant C)=1$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event $\{|\xi_1|+|\xi_2|+|\xi_3|>C\}$ can be written as disjoint union of $8$ events and one of them is: $$\{|\xi_1|+|\xi_2|+|\xi_3|>C\}\cap\{\xi_1\geq0\}\cap\{\xi_2\geq0\}\cap\{\xi_3\geq0\}\tag1$$

To make clear which events I mean let me tell you that one of the others is e.g.:$$\{|\xi_1|+|\xi_2|+|\xi_3|>C\}\cap\{\xi_1<0\}\cap\{\xi_2<0\}\cap\{\xi_3\geq0\}$$

Now if $P(|\xi_1|+|\xi_2|+|\xi_3|>C)>0$ then also the event mentioned in $(1)$ has positive probability. This on base of the fact that this event is the one among the $8$ that has maximal probability.

This however implies that also the event $\{|\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3|>C\}$ must have positive probability. This on base of the fact that the event in $(1)$ is a subset of $\{|\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3|>C\}$.

So a contradiction has been found.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is enough for you then you can choose for accepting it.